# error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `color'

Tags: unity-game-engine, unassigned-variable

I got this error when compiling a unity game. How to fix this ?

Thanks

Assets/spine-unity/Mesh Generation/Arrays/ArraysMeshGenerator.cs(221,21): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `color'

And another 
Assets/spine-unity/Mesh Generation/Arrays/ArraysMeshGenerator.cs(157,19): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `color'

Line 157

```
colors[vi] = color; colors[vi + 1] = color; colors[vi + 2] = color; colors[vi + 3] = color;
```

Line 221

```
colors[vi] = color; uvs[vi].x = attachmentUVs[iii]; uvs[vi].y = attachmentUVs[iii + 1];
```

Comment: Hello. Please add the relevant code to the question instead of as a screenshot.

Comment: I am guessing but most likely you are declaring your array like that varType color[]; and you don't initialize it any anywhere.

Comment: Include your code *in* your question please, we don't want to go to an external resource that may not exist in 10 years.

Comment: Tried to attach the code in the last 10 minutes, but still got the red box error. Please wait

Comment: Please do not attach your full code, but the piece that crashes ! No one will ever read pages of random code

Answer (score 3):

Replace line 116

```
Color32 color;
```

with

```
Color32 color = default(Color);
```

Source code (which has the problem):

https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/blob/3.4.02/spine-unity/Assets/spine-unity/Mesh%20Generation/Arrays/ArraysMeshGenerator.cs

This is assuming you are using an older version of spine-runtimes like v3.4 as your code and line numbers suggest.

If you upgrade to the latest Spine Unity runtime (for instance version 3.6.39), you will also have this problem, but in a different file (SpineMesh.cs):

https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/blob/3.6.39/spine-unity/Assets/spine-unity/Mesh%20Generation/SpineMesh.cs

In this case, apply the same fix to lines 460 and 664.